# Breaking threading.Timer when a function is executed

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I set a timer in Python for, lets say, 20 seconds, but in between if another function is called, then the timer should break.

Is there any way to execute this using Python's `threading.Timer`?

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`timer.cancel()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Timer.cancel) in the body of the function that should interrupt it.

```
def some_func():
   print "Some function that runs after a timeout"


def interrupt_func():
   timer.cancel()  # some_func will no longer be called
   # other stuff

timer = threading.Timer(20, some_func)
time.sleep(10)
interrupt_func()
```

Comment: how will i check  whether the timer is still running or not in interrupt_func() ?

Comment: @PranavRaj You can call `cancel` even if the timer has already expired, but you could call `timer.finished.is_set()` to see the timer has been marked as "finished", meaning it either ran or was cancelled.

Comment: Be careful about making decisions based on is_set. If its False, the timer could fire at any time... even before your next line of code.